# Validation: want to return only numbers true in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation, symbols

Right now, if given any float or integer I want this condition to return 'true', whereas 'false' on any special character or any random characters added.

```
const float = (value) => {
return !isNaN(Number(value)) && isFinite(value); };
```

It is Not working fine with '&' and '%' symbols.
As `!isNaN(Number(18.&4)) && isFinite(18.&4);` or `!isNaN(Number(1%8.4)) && isFinite(1%8.4);` is True under this condition and I want it to be False.

All symbols not passing through condition: ` , " , ~ , and ,

Comment: Are you passing the string `"18.&4"` or directly entering that expression? Those mean entirely different things.

Comment: If you enter expression directly it would execute, @Unmitigated is correct, you should pass it as string to be working. Otherwise value param in function would get calculated result.

Comment: @Unmitigated passing value as string.

Comment: @LostStranger how should I alter my current function?

Comment: I tried executing in console, but it seems to return correct values if you pass them as string.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an additional check for invalid characters in the input value before passing it to Number function.

```
const isFloat = (value) => {
// Check if the input value contains invalid characters
  if (/[^\d.-]/.test(value)) return false;
  return !isNaN(Number(value)) && isFinite(value);
};
```

The `/[^\d.-]/` regular expression matches any characters that are not digits (\d), periods (.), or dashes (-),

Comment: This won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This avoids all special characters, and alphabets.. Allows dots and digits.

```
const CheckSpecialCharacters = (value) => {
        if (/^[a-zA-Z_.]*$/.test(value)) return false;
        return true;
    };
    
const float = (value) => {
    return (
        CheckSpecialCharacters(value) &&
        !isNaN(Number(value)) &&
        isFinite(value) &&
        Number(value) >= 0
    );
};
```